# Express Mongoose is not saving data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have some trouble saving a object I made in Express nodejs using mongoose.

***It always says its saved but can never find the object even if i log into the server and try to get it myself.***

Express route to save mongodb:

```
router.post('/share', function(req, res, next){
  //console.log('Post Request Made', req);

    //switch to be inputed as parameters of the request
    //save share
    var share = new Shares({ link: req.body.link, description: req.body.description });
//  var share = new Shares({ req.data.link, req.data.description });
  console.log('request body', req.body);
  console.log('to be added', share);
    //save to database
    share.save(function(err, share){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('the object was saved' , share);
      var id  = share._id;
      res.send(id);
        }
    });
});
```

Console log:

```
request body { link: 'test', description: 'test' }
to be added { link: 'test',
  description: 'test',
  _id: 5840b0393181d4000f652cba,
  clicks: 0 }
the object was saved { __v: 0,
  link: 'test',
  description: 'test',
  _id: 5840b0393181d4000f652cba,
  clicks: 0 }
POST /share 200 73.618 ms - 26
This is the link page with id:  5840b0393181d4000f652cba
found []
GET /fluff/link/5840b0393181d4000f652cba 200 20.387 ms - 266
```

Configuration:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo/shares');
require('./models/Shares');
```

Comment: Do you check the mongo db to see it stored or not?

Comment: I actually solved it just now. I didn't change in the database to make sure I was in the correct area after that I turned on the debug option in mongoose and then did the proper query method will post my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. My problem was that I'm a noob in `mongo` shell and mongodb in general.

I was actually saving properly, but the way I was searching in the `mongo` shell was wrong. I didn't realize every time your in the `mongo` shell it starts in the `test` database if you run `mongo` with no arguments.

So first thing is to enter the database that you want to be in:

```
    `mongo [database_name]`
```

then check for any documents in there by:

```
   `db.collections.count()`
   `db.collections.find()`
```

My real problem was that my `Shares.findById()` was wrong and I had to look up the proper parameters.

this is what the *working* version looks like now:

```
  Shares.findById(id.toString(), function(err, share){
    if(err){
          console.log('error', err);
        } else {
            console.log('found', share);
        }
  });
```